# Uncaught Error: The template specified for component AppComponent is not a string

Tags: angular, webpack, angular7

I am trying to upgrade my angular 5, webpack 2.2 project to angular 7 with webpack 4.4. Here's my updated package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "7.0.0-beta.19",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.20",
    "@types/datatables.net": "1.10.13",
    "@types/handsontable": "^0.35.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.5",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.10",
    "angular2-csv": "^0.2.9",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "2.5.7",
    "css": "^2.2.4",
    "d3": "^4.7.3",
    "datatables.net": "^2.1.1",
    "datatables.net-bs": "^2.1.1",
    "datatables.net-select": "^1.2.7",
    "datatables.net-select-bs": "^1.2.7",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "event-source-polyfill": "1.0.4",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "ng2-handsontable": "^2.1.0-rc.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.6",
    "preboot": "6.0.0-beta.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "shepherd.js": "2.0.0-beta.35",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "typescript-watcher": "0.0.4",
    "url-loader": "1.1.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "3.3.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.11",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-loader": "1.0.0-alpha.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.4",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
    "karma": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^4.0.0-rc.4",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "0.20.3",
    "typescript": "3.1.6",
    "webpack": "4.4.1",
    "webpack-cli": "2.0.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4"
  }
```

I have tried various loaders for loading the HTML (some are still included in package.json). I used loaders like raw-loader and to-string-loader to see if it would make any difference (which it does not).

Here's my webpack common config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './ClientApp/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './ClientApp/vendor.ts',
        'app': './ClientApp/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: [
                    {
                        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                        options: { configFileName: helpers.root('ClientApp', 'tsconfig.json') }
                    } , 'angular2-template-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'html-loader'
                }] //'to-string-loader', 
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: helpers.root('ClientApp', 'app'),
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader?sourceMap' })
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('ClientApp', 'app'),
                loader: 'css-loader' //['raw-loader', 'to-string-loader']
            }
        ]
    },

    optimization:
    {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: "vendors",
                    chunks: "all"
                }
            }
        }
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)fesm5/,
            helpers.root('ClientApp'), //./
            {}
        ),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'Views/Home/Index.cshtml'
        })
    ]
};
```

This is how I include all templates for my components:

```
@Component({
    selector: "app",
    template: require("./app.component.html"),
    styles: ["./app.component.css"]
})
```

(Used to be templateUrl: "./app.component.html", which seems to make no difference)

Now I am stuck on this error:

[image]
I hope somebody can help me with this, since i have been stuck on this error for a week now. Thank you!

**EDIT**
When I use "styleUrls" instead of "styles" a somewhat similar error is shown: 
`Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone still has this error then add this line in your app.component.ts

```
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
```

if this generates "Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings." then add following loaders hope it solves all problems

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: 'html-loader' //raw-loader
},
{
    test: /\.css$/,
//  include: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'app'),
    use: [
        'to-string-loader', 'css-loader',
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
```

You don't need to `require()` a template, or templateUrl, to be more specific. Just provide the correct relative path. Note also that I'm using `templateUrl`, not `template`. Same goes for `styleUrls`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick reply! I used to use "templateUrl" before the upgrade, which worked perfectly fine. I happened to end up using 'template' because of trail and error debugging. But now templateUrl shows the same error as template. Also, when I use styleUrls, I get `"Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings."` Again, this used to work in angular 5 with webpack 2.2.

Comment: Actually, TIL, your original syntax works. I think the `styles` issue will go away if you include `to-string-loader` that you commented out.

Comment: @JasperWiggerink is your issue solved. I am having same issue now when i am trying to upgrade angular 5 to angular 7.2 . Please suggest me solution if you could get it.

Comment: @Sando It's been a long time so i'm not sure what solved it (should have logged it somewhere, sorry). However, I now use 'raw-loader' for html and 'to-string-loader' and 'css-loader' for css. I have also got rid of the first css rule with the ExtractTextPlugin. Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

The error likely has something to do with incompatible TypeScript versions.

First of all you should NOT upgrade directly over several major versions. when upgrading from Angular 5 to 7, upgrade to Angular 6 first, then to v7 (see https://angular.io/guide/releases#supported-update-paths).

It's also quite comfortable to use the CLI update feature: https://angular.io/guide/releases#supported-update-paths
It takes care that all relevant packages and dependencies (e.g. correct typescript version) are installed, uninstalls angular-packages that are not used anymore (e.g. when they were incorporated in other packages) and provides information about what has to be refactored or refactors some code automatically, if possible.

In any case, it is a good idea to follow the Angular Upgrade Guide: https://update.angular.io/
It also tells you which steps you have to take and what might be required to be done manually to successfully upgrade Angular.

**But concerning the concrete problem:** 
In the case described in the question, the Angular team probably changed how `template` is handled (i.e. that it actually has to be a real string). And `require("./app.component.html")` is not a string.
So @Peter Kim 's answer should have solved you problem.

I had a similar case when upgrading from Angular 7 to Angular 8: We used a correct string with a correct path for `templateUrl`, but got the error

> Error: The template specified for component XXX is not a string

I'm not completely sure if it was the TypeScript version or the change from `commonjs` to `esnext` and from `"target": "es5"` to `es2015` (see tsconfig.json), but my guess is the first.
When those don't match the version the Angular Compiler uses, the interpretation of strings (or their type, to be more precise) could differ. So, although the path is a correct string you can get that error.

In mycase it was a little "obvious", because although we use `templateUrl`, I got the `template` error, which the compiler handles first.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbled upon this, you should use native angular '@ngtools/webpack' plugin as a loader instead of 'angular2-template-loader':

```
const { AngularWebpackPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');
...
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loader: '@ngtools/webpack'
        },
    ...    
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new AngularWebpackPlugin({
        jitMode: true, // false=AOT by default
    }),
    ...
]
```

In JIT mode it works similar to angular2-template-loader and uses raw-loader during runtime, but AOT mode is preferrable. More at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack
The problem is that in AOT mode most of angular compilerOptions don't work (defaultEncapsulation in particular) - Angular uses default values (as of 12.0.0-rc.1)